# Implement two-way data binding for custom property

Tags: angular, primeng

I see in primeng components the use something like ngModel (two-way data binding) style for some property like this

```
[(selection)]="selectedItem";
```

it 's look like

```
@Input() selection;
@Output() selection:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

how I can implement something like this and is it possible to do for more than single property like

```
 <component-a  [(selection)]="selectedItem"  [(data)]="selectedData"></component-a>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

```
<app-sizer 
  [(size)]="fontSizePx">
</app-sizer>
```

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a
>   property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the
>   binding into this:

```
<app-sizer
  [size]="fontSizePx"
  (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event">
</app-sizer>
```

To create two-way binding for property `selection` use:

```
@Input() selection;

// You have to follow this convention (For Output property)
// i.e. <propertyName><Change> like selectionChange

@Output() selectionChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And to change selection in  component as shown below:

```
changeSelection(newSelection)
{
    this.selection = newSelection;

    // emit change event to parent component
    this.selectionChange.emit(this.selection);  
}
```

Comment: How selectionChange.emit() will be called?

Comment: as in the example emit will trigger manually after the value in the component has changed @DmitriySnitko

Answer (score 16):

In your child component you have to implement two-way binding interface like this:

```
private _selection: any;
get selection(): any {
    return this._selection;
}
@Input()
set selection(value: any) {
    if(this._selection === value) {
        return;
    }
    this._selection = value;
    this.selectionChange.emit(this._selection);
}
@Output()
selectionChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

It's mandatory to name `@Output` filed by adding `propertyNameChange` to `@Input` name.
So you can use it in your parent component temlate like this:

```
<mycomponent [(selection)]="fieldInParentComponent"></mycomponent>
```

Answer (score 9):

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding

> The `[(x)]` syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable property called x and a corresponding event named `xChange`.

This means, you only need a corresponding `selectionChange` method on your child component.  Hence, if you want the banana-in-a-box binding for your property `selection` of `ParentComponent` into `ChildComponent`, follow these steps:

1. Include the following in your `ChildComponent`:

   ```
   @Input() selection;
   @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
   ```
2. In your `ParentComponent` template:

   ```
   <child [(selection)]="selection">
   ```

In summary, if your property name is `x`, you only need to name its corresponding EventEmitter to `xChange` and do the banana-in-a-box syntax for the child component `[(x)] = "parentProperty"` and Angular takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In your child component (component-a) you need an `@output`

```
@Output() change:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

and then you notify parent component about a changed value by

```
change.emit(newValue);
```

See also Angular2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33220997/3710630

Comment: Can you check my answer my gole is to create a proprty to be use like ngModel  as input and output

Comment: Calling .next() on EventEmitter is deprecated. Use emit instead